# Redirigir a otra vista con Get en un ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy usando el paquete clickable_list_wheel_view y dentro de cada child estoy queriendo usar Get para redirigir a otra vista pero no se ejecuta el metodo tap().

```
class Prueba extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
  static const double _itemHeight = 160;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ClickableListWheelScrollView(
      scrollController: _scrollController,
      itemHeight: _itemHeight,
      itemCount: _itemCount,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
onItemTapCallback: (index) {
    print("onItemTapCallback index: $index");
  },` child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
    offAxisFraction: -1.6,
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemExtent: _itemHeight,
    physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
    overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
    perspective: 0.002,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {},
    childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
      builder: (context, index) => _child(index),
      childCount: _itemCount,
    ),
  ),
));


Widget _child(int index) {
return SizedBox(
  height: _itemHeight,
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
        IconData(int.parse("0xe${index + 200}"),
            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
        size: 50),
    title: Text('Heart Shaker'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
    onTap: () {
      print('hola');
      Get.to(HomePage());
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Este es el codigo que implemente.Si me ejecuta el print el metodo onItemTapCallback() pero no el tap() que esta en el widget de abajo.
Soy nuevo en flutter.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la razón por la cuál no detecta el onTap en tu widgte ListTitle es debido a que el ClickableListWheelScrollView como tal ya es un envoltorio para ListWheelScrollView, entonces para resolver su problema solo debe de asegurar colocar su Get.to(HomePage()); en onItemTapCallback de tu clickableListWheelScrollView o onSelectedItemChanged de tu ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate, según sea tu caso. Ejemplo...

```
class Prueba extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
  static const double _itemHeight = 160;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ClickableListWheelScrollView(
        scrollController: _scrollController,
        itemHeight: _itemHeight,
        itemCount: _itemCount,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        onItemTapCallback: (index) {
         print("onItemTapCallback index: $index");
         /*Get.to(HomePage());*/
         },
         child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
           offAxisFraction: -1.6,
           controller: _scrollController,
           itemExtent: _itemHeight,
           physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
           overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
           perspective: 0.002,
           onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
              /*Get.to(HomePage());*/
           },
           childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
             builder: (context, index) => _child(index),
             childCount: _itemCount,
           ),
         ),
    ));
}


Widget _child(int index) {
return SizedBox(
  height: _itemHeight,
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
        IconData(int.parse("0xe${index + 200}"),
            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
        size: 50),
    title: Text('Heart Shaker'),
    subtitle: Text('Description here'),
  ),
);
}
```